# how to display Canvas in current activity Image view in android

Tags: android

```
public class AndroidBarcodeView extends ImageView {

    public AndroidBarcodeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        try {

            testQRCode(canvas);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static void testQRCode(Canvas canvas) throws Exception {
        QRCode barcode = new QRCode();

        /*
         * QRCode Valid data char set: numeric data (digits 0 - 9); alphanumeric
         * data (digits 0 - 9; upper case letters A -Z; nine other characters:
         * space, $ % * + - . / : ); byte data (default: ISO/IEC 8859-1); Kanji
         * characters
         */
        // BIZCARD:N:Kelly;X:Goto;T:Design Ethnographer;C:gotomedia LLC;A:2169
        // Folsom Street
        // M302;B:4158647007;F:4158647004;M:4159907005;E:kelly@gotomedia.com;;
        // barcode.setData("BIZCARD:N:Kelly;X:Goto;T:Design Ethnographer;C:gotomedia LLC;A:2169 Folsom Street M302;B:4158647007;F:4158647004;M:4159907005;E:kelly@gotomedia.com;;");

        barcode.setData("StudentId:11;SectionId:A2;TimeStamp:20-04-2015 12:18PM;;");

        barcode.setDataMode(QRCode.M_AUTO);
        barcode.setVersion(1);
        barcode.setEcl(QRCode.ECL_L);

        // if you want to encode GS1 compatible QR Code, you need set FNC1 mode
        // to IBarcode.FNC1_ENABLE
        barcode.setFnc1Mode(IBarcode.FNC1_NONE);

        // Set the processTilde property to true, if you want use the tilde
        // character "~" to specify special characters in the input data.
        // Default is false.
        // 1-byte character: ~ddd (character value from 0 ~ 255)
        // ASCII (with EXT): from ~000 to ~255
        // 2-byte character: ~6ddddd (character value from 0 ~ 65535)
        // Unicode: from ~600000 to ~665535
        // ECI: from ~7000000 to ~7999999
        // SJIS: from ~9ddddd (Shift JIS 0x8140 ~ 0x9FFC and 0xE040 ~ 0xEBBF)
        barcode.setProcessTilde(false);

        // unit of measure for X, Y, LeftMargin, RightMargin, TopMargin,
        // BottomMargin
        barcode.setUom(IBarcode.UOM_PIXEL);
        // barcode module width in pixel
        barcode.setX(3f);

        barcode.setLeftMargin(50f);
        barcode.setRightMargin(50f);
        barcode.setTopMargin(50f);
        barcode.setBottomMargin(50f);
        // barcode image resolution in dpi
        barcode.setResolution(72);

        // barcode bar color and background color in Android device
        barcode.setForeColor(AndroidColor.black);
        barcode.setBackColor(AndroidColor.white);

        /*
         * specify your barcode drawing area
         */
        RectF bounds = new RectF(0, 0, 0, 0);
        barcode.drawBarcode(canvas, bounds);
    }

}
```

using this am able to generate bar-code :

This is my code :

```
 Imageview img;
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.textView3) {
            AndroidBarcodeView view = new AndroidBarcodeView(
                    StudentManinPage.this);
            setContentView(view);
        }

    }
```

where i have to display Barcode on Imageview  But when i click on generate bar code then it display barcode   but it doesnot display in current actvity imageview it display in another view please help me to display in current activity on imageview  i have img imageview .

Comment: RectF bounds = new RectF(0, 0, 0, 0); try to give a real size for this. RectF bounds = new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()); And make sure your ImageView has not zero size.

Comment: this code we have to Put in Actvity na ? and how to display it in imageview please Edid my code so that ic an implemnt

Comment: @user1531179 this line of code located in your testQRCode method. And you should replace this line.

Comment: RectF bounds = new RectF(0, 0, 0, 0);
   canvas.getWidth();
   canvas.getHeight();
 code i have added in that now i will call and display it in Imageview

Comment: @user1531179 wrong. Replace RectF bounds = new RectF(0, 0, 0, 0); with RectF bounds = new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

Comment: I have RectF bounds = new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());  written this now how i will call it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75713/discussion-between-user1531170-and-vladimir-kulyk).

Comment: @VladimirKulyk please tell how i will display it in imageview  http://pastebin.com/SXQZHpwS   here is my actvity class

Answer (score 0):

I won't write code for you. This is just an answer on your question:

Find and replace `RectF bounds = new RectF(0, 0, 0, 0);` with `RectF bounds = new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());`

---

```
public class AndroidBarcodeView extends ImageView {
    //...
    private static void testQRCode(Canvas canvas) throws Exception {
      //...
      RectF bounds = new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
      barcode.drawBarcode(canvas, bounds);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class StudentManinPage extends Activity {
  //...
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      AndroidBarcodeView bar_code_view = new AndroidBarcodeView(this);
      bar_code_view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

      setContentView(bar_code_view);
      //...
  }
  //...
}
```

Comment: But still i am unable to display that bar code in Imageview