# how to get all checked value on button click from list-view in android

Tags: android

This is my adapter class :

```
 public class CheckboxAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        Context context;
        private String[] mStrings;
        private TypedArray mIcons;
        private int mViewResourceId;
        ArrayList<String> selectedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

        public CheckboxAdapter(Context ctx, int viewResourceId, String[] strings) {
            super(ctx, viewResourceId, strings);

            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            mStrings = strings;

            mViewResourceId = viewResourceId;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mStrings.length;
        }

        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mStrings[position];
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

            final CheckBox tv = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            tv.setText(mStrings[position]);
            tv.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (isChecked) {
                        selectedStrings.add(tv.getText().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(buttonView.getContext(),Boolean.toString(selectedStrings.add(tv.getText().toString())), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        selectedStrings.remove(tv.getText().toString());
                    }

                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

This is my actvity

```
public class AddTime extends Activity {
    CheckboxAdapter cadpter;

    String daya[] = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thrusday",
            "Friday", "Saturday" };
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<String> selectedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addtime);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        cadpter = new CheckboxAdapter(AddTime.this, R.layout.list_item, daya);
        list.setAdapter(cadpter);

    }

}
```

I am displaying all day  in listview  also i have display check box with each day when i enable check box it show true in toast  but i want what ever i select day using check box i mean i want display all the day in textview in mainactvity please suggest me how i will get it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to get all checked value on button click from list-view in android

As adding all checked values in `selectedStrings` ArrayList. create a method in `CheckboxAdapter` class which return ArrayList of all selected values. for example :

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllSelectedValues(){
  return this.selectedStrings;
 }
```

Now use `cadpter` `CheckboxAdapter` class object for accessing  `getAllSelectedValues`method in Activity:

```
ArrayList<String> selectedStrings=cadpter.getAllSelectedValues();
```

Comment: Ok wait let me check  thnku

Comment: it works but i am getting two time value http://snag.gy/YAq7v.jpg  please check this screen

Comment: @user1531170: ok. use `HashSet` instead of ArrayList to avoid duplicate values

Comment: @user1531170: or just do it as `ArrayList<String> selectedStrings = new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(cadpter.getAllSelectedValues()))`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747312/how-to-display-canvas-in-current-activity-image-view-in-android    @ρяσѕρєя K  can u please check this issue am stucking in this issue from long time

Answer (score 0):

get all values from selectedStrings arrayList

```
for(int i=0;i<=selectedStrings.sizes();i++){
String s =selectedStrings.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take boolean Array

```
ArrayList<Boolean> selectedStrings = new ArrayList<>();
```

and add onClickListener in your checkbox

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           -
           -
            tv.setChecked(false);
            if(selectedStrings.size() <= position){
                selectedStrings.add(position, false);
            }else
                tv.setChecked(selectedStrings.get(position));
            tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean state = selectedStrings.get(position);
            selectedStrings.remove(position);
            selectedStrings.add(position, state ? false : true);

                }
            });
}
```

Comment: fetch out the selected days from the selectedStrings Array for all true values, try this